# Import path when using import on remote server

Tags: phpmyadmin, import

As many others I have a db that is too large and bigdump does not seem to work, the page script appears all garbled with code, so I go for the command but cant find the correct path to my database. I am not using neither cli nor ssh. Trying this via SQL command

As mentioned its on a webhost and I can browse directories in a file manager but after several attempts I just cant make out the correct path to my uploaded sql... any tips on that would be appreciated.

I can not edit the phpmyadmin file limitations, not my server.

Comment: What kind of DBMS is that?

Comment: You should contact the hosting provider support to provide the information. We cannot guess how your hosting provider arranges its directories.

Comment: We're unable to assist with shared web hosting here. You may be able to get help on our sister site, [webmasters.se].

Comment: Any alternatives to bigdump out there?